# Disable Link Preview in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

Im trying to create a small app for myself.
It should show just a page in webView.
This allready works but I try to disallow the function to see the preview of a Link in the webView.

If you hold a Link longer and harder then a regular part of the App, the preview will activate.

How to disable this?

Sorry for bad english and the question. Im a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is no longer accepted, use WKWebView instead. It has **allowsLinkPreview** to disable link preview. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415000-allowslinkpreview?language=objc